# Is there a function to see my request payload that's being sent inside a POST request?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to login to a website, and get a specific GET request, however, I am not sure if I'm doing it correctly. I'll explain some details.

The website is set up like this: The login page: `example.com/something/login` The post request URL that's being sent when i login: `example.com/something/token` and the GET request I need: URL: `website.com/something/info`

My issue is that my code does not seem to log me in because when I try to get `website.com/something/info` it returns a response 401. I'm not sure if my code isn't sending the payload, or my code is incorrect.

My issue could also be that I'm using the wrong URL. I am using `example.com/something/login` but I'm not sure if I should be using `example.com/something/login` or `example.com/something/token` (what appears to be what appears to be sent when I log in)

Also I should link the request payload of `token`:

grant_type=password&username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD&scope=3

```py
import requests
with requests.Session() as session:
  session.post("example.com/something/login"), data={
  'grant_type':'password',
  'username':'MYUSERNAME',
  'password':'MYPASSWORD',
  'scope':'3'
  })
  print(session.get("example.com/something/info"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the URL you shared it looks like you need to pass the arguments as [query parameters](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls). To specify that with `requests.Session` that would be:

```py
import requests
with requests.Session() as session:
  res_post = session.post("example.com/something/token", params={
    'grant_type':'password',
    'username':'MYUSERNAME',
    'password':'MYPASSWORD',
    'scope':'3'
    })
  print(f'post status: {res_post.status_code}')
  print(f'post status: {res_post.data}')
  res_get = session.get("example.com/something/info", headers={'Authorization': f"Bearer {res_post.json()['token']}"})
  print(f'get status: {res_get.status_code}')
  print(f'get status: {res_get.data}')
```

Comment: The `res.status_code` gives me response 405... does this mean the website does not allow it or am I doing something wrong? Also, the exact message is: `{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}`, (This error is from session.get("website.com/something/info") )

Comment: Yes, this means that the route `/something/login` is most likely not implemented yet. Double check if it is the correct one to establish a login/bearer token. You will most likely need to add a header `Authorization: Bearer <token>` to your `GET /something/info` request. Since the login failed the second error seems expected.

Comment: Yes the wehsite does not allow it, or an error in my code?

Comment: Code seems fine with exception of the syntax error (extra parenthesis in post). Which website is it? How do you know what is the correct route for requesting a login/bearer token? Updated my answer with more debug info.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the correct route for requesting a login/bearer token, I just thought since the 'token' post comes from the login page it would come from there.

Comment: If there is a web GUI page already, you can 'reverse engineer' it. Try these steps:
1) Open Google Chrome
2) Navigate to the site and logout
3) Open up the developer tools (CRTL + F12 usually)
4) Navigate to the `Network` tab
5) Try logging in the page
6) Review all the requests that were sent in the developer tools until you find a POST request that is trying to login, it should tell you how to structure your request

Comment: The POST request that is being sent when I login is called `token`

Comment: Is this for a website that is public already? Or is the source code committed to GitHub? If you share a link I can probably tell you right away.

Comment: OK, updated my answer using `/something/token`

Comment: It's my school website for grades, i can't link it exactly as it would tell you too much about me but i can link one that appears to be the exact same (same post requests being sent) 
https://fdvm1sisapp1.tylertech.com/SISPlus360/apphost/TylerSis#/login

Comment: No problem. That is a great practice to have :) Reviewed the link you shared. The latest update to my answer should work for you now.